# How to read MapInfo .tab files in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, convert, spatial-database, tab

I want to use arcpy (the ESRI install of python 2.65) to analyse MapInfo TAB files...can this be done directly or do I need to convert them to shp files...if so would it be possible to do something like

```
tabs=glob.glob('*.tab') and then
for tab in tabs
 some function to convert tab to shp tab_shp1.shp
```

> (maybe ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" mydata.shp mydata.tab) not sure how
>   to call an external command line.

```
 shpObj=arcpy.Describe(tab_shp1)
 etc
```

I know there is functionality in [FWTOOLS via OGR](http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=ogr_cheatsheet) but can I access this via the ESRI python 2.65 install?

We have both tab and shp data and I am trying to create a master spatial index of all the datasets we have. I have written the code for ESRI formats but want to include the tab's if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have OGR installed you should be able to use OGR in python.

```
import ogr
ds = ogr.Open("Path")
```

There is some explains of usinig Python OGR on here http://www.gdal.org/ogr/ogr_apitut.html

Comment: Thanks guys...haven't had time to evaluate the answers here. Will get back ASAP

Comment: You'll need to ensure the ogr python bindings are installed for the same python that Arcgis is using. [This recipe](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134/can-arcgis-and-osgeo4w-share-the-same-python-install) worked for Arcgis 9.3, I haven't tried anything similar for 10 yet.

Answer (score 2):

From the [ArcGIS Resource Center](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//004m00000012000000.htm):

> Complexity: Beginner
>
> Data Requirement: ArcGIS Tutorial Data Setup
>
> Data Path: C:\arcgis\ArcTutor\Data Interoperability\
>
> Goal:  Learn how to work with nonnative datasets in ArcMap when the
>   Data Interoperability extension is enabled.  Direct-read formats are
>   used directly from the Catalog tree as read-only datasets. When you
>   add them to ArcMap, ArcScene, or ArcGlobe, all standard map functions
>   are enabled, including attribute tables and labeling functions.
>
> ...

**You can see the quick import tool as part of the data interoperability tools toolkit - This can also be batch processed.**

Comment: Finding this resource is great, Hairy, but please follow standard practice for re-using material.  **It is of paramount importance to attribute other people's material**, preferably with a link (which I have supplied).  Furthermore, extracting large blocks of text is usually not acceptable: instead, provide the link and a summary (either in your own words or with selected quotations).  For more information, please consult the [site policy](http://stackexchange.com/legal) (section 3) and make sure to respect the copyright on the site you are citing (it appears at the bottom of the page).