# Using osgeo modules in ArcGIS10.1 and QGIS 1.8 python shells

Tags: qgis, python, arcpy, gdal, ogr

This is related to an old question of mine - [Issues with osgeo - qgis.core and arcpy modules](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19646/issues-with-osgeo-qgis-core-and-arcpy-modules)

Now in new versions of all the software QGIS Lisboa (1.8), ArcGIS 10.1 and pyScripter  2.5.3. They all use python 2.7

I can't get the following to work.

```
>>> import osgeo
>>> from osgeo import ogr
```

arcgis 10.1 and pyscripter fail here.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.chdir(r'L:\Data_Admin\QA\test_data\Boundaries\Local_Govt\TRC\TAB')
>>> driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('MapInfo File')
>>> fn='trc_boundary.tab'
>>> dataSource=driver.Open(fn,0)
>>> layer = dataSource.GetLayer(0)
```

>

> > > feature = layer.GetFeature(0)
> > >       extent=layer.GetExtent()
> > >       extent
> > >           (-12895.844282306107, 376810.87105960253, 7944810.84780738, 8222992.984638059)
> > >       numFeatures=layer.GetFeatureCount()
> > >       geometry = feature.GetGeometryRef()
> > >           Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >             File "", line 1, in 
> > >           AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetGeometryRef'

QGIS python shell fails here. Not sure why - I checked http://www.gdal.org/ogr/classOGRGeometryCollection.html but it is not helpful.

my

> PYTHONPATH=C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\python27; C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa

I have installed the gdal python bindings for arcgis but then where is ogr?

also I can't seem to run

```
from osgeo import gdal
dataset = gdal.open("c:/abc.img")
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line
>   1, in  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'open'

Comment: Sounds like two rather independent questions to me. Please consider splitting it up.

Comment: I want to get it to work in both the qgis and arcgis python modules...so I feel it should be connected.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few odd things going on here:

- Python is case sensitive. Thus `gdal.open` does not exist, but `gdal.Open` *does* exist.
- `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetGeometryRef'` means that you tried to get a feature that did not exist. I.e., `layer.GetFeature(0)` returned `None`, so there are no features in that layer.
- "I have installed the gdal python bindings for arcgis but then where is ogr?" How doyou know? If `from osgeo import gdal` works, did you try `from osgeo import ogr`?
- The `PYTHONPATH` looks busy. Are they all the same version and platform of Python?

Answer (score 0):

I use ArcGIS 10 and QGIS 1.8, but I have managed to use PyScripter for both. I have recently [written a blog post](http://mapoholic.wordpress.com/2012/06/28/configure-pyscripter-qgis/) for this. In your case it should be easier.

My python paths for 2.7.2 is:

> 'C:\Windows\system32\python27.zip', 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\DLLs', 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib', 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win',
>   'C:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS
>   Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk', 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\qgis\bin', 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27', 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages',
>   'C:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS
>   Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL', 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32',
>   'C:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS
>   Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib', 'C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Quantum GIS
>   Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin', 'C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Quantum GIS
>   Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode',
>   'C:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS
>   Lisboa\apps\qgis\python\plugins\fTools\tools'

Comment: Thanks mate. I followed the steps and when the .color is included you get a message that the command line window color is changed and when I get rid of all that I get pyscripter can not be found and now I can't import arcpy either. Is this because 10.1 uses python 2.7. I checked the reg file you provided and it doesn't seem to mention c:\python27 where arcgis python bindings are so I ran your reg file as I assumed it wouldn't affect arcpy.

Comment: Blimey. OK, yes- it would make sense if you just ran the reg file as-is. I use ArcGIS10 which uses Python26. So if you just ran the reg file it would have pointed to the QGIS 2.7 install. Also, the reason of the reg file is that QGIS does not add any of the Python settings in the registry and PyScripter requires that to know which version of Python to run. In your case however, the registy settings would already been there as ArcGIS (I guess in version 10.1 as well) DOES put these reg settings.

Comment: (continued) So basically, you will need to merge these settings (ArcGIS and QGIS) in the registry.